# ExpressionEngine wiki talk forum module

Tags: expressionengine

I just started using the ExpressionEngine wiki talk forum extension and it is great for creating forum topics per each wiki article but, I also need it to add discussions for wiki file pages too.

My users have the need to not only discuss wiki articles but, to also discuss uploaded files. Any thoughts on how to add this feature to wiki talk forum extension?

Comment: You'd probably get a lot more help in the EE forums than here.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, this isn't a nativity available feature--you'd have to do some hacking...if I were you, I'd wait until EE 2.0 comes out--some time in December!